# Obtaining output of Iron.io worker with PhantomJs

Tags: phantomjs, iron.io

I'm writing this application that uses some information from a website and I'm using PhantomJs to extract this information. Now I want the user to be able to run my application without the need of PhantomJs in their system. That way it'll be more like a service call.

I have followed the following guide: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/07/cloud-phantomjs-with-ironworker.html

To get PhantomJs working and getting the information that I need for some site, now I can queue a worker and get the result in the log using Iron.io's web interface.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the result of the execution programmatically. I have taken a look at the [API](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/api/), but I need to authenticate and I also need to provide a different task ID ( which I don't know how to get ).

Answer (score 4):

Queue task => obtain `task_id` as result of operation.

But there are plenty of different ways to get result:
read task log via api (you need project_id, token, task_id), Store data to Amazon S3, push information to some kind of queue, touch own api, send info to webhook, write information to database etc